# Can anyone explain this code? I do not understand the working of not1() and ptr_fun()

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Can anyone explain the working of this function?

```cpp
string rightTrim(const string &str)
{
    string s(str);
    s.erase(find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace))).base(), s.end());
    return s;
}
```

I don't know the working of `not1()` and `ptr_fun()`. Can anyone provide me with a good explanation for this code?

PS: I know, this code removes any white spaces from the end of the string.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1

Comment: Looks like it wants to remove all trailing spaces from a string by starting at the back looking for a non-isspace character. (rbegin, rend iterates of string from back to front)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is essentially

> *What is `not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace))`?*

### Short answer

You should use `std::not_fn(isspace)` instead, which clearly states it is a "thing" that expresses the idea that "something is not a space".(¹)(²)

### Wordy answer

It is a predicated that asks if its input is *not* a space: if you apply it to `'a'` you get `true`, if you apply it to `' '`, you get `false`.

However, one the *not* in the paragraph above explains the reason why the code has `not1`, but it doesn't say anything about `ptr_fun`. What is *that* for? Why couldn't we just write `not1(isspace)`?

Long story short, [`not1` is an old generation helper function which was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1). It relies on the argument that you pass to it to have a member type named `argument_type`, but `isspace` is a free function, not an object of a class providing such a member, so `not1(isspace)` is ill formed.

`ptr_fun` came to the rescue, as it can transform `isspace` in an object which provides the interface that `not1` expects.

However, [`ptr_fun` was deprecated even before `not1`, in C++11, and removed in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun).

The bottom line is therefore that you should not use either of those: you don't need `ptr_fun` anymore, and you can use [`not_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn) as a more usable alternative to `not1`. You can indeed just change <s>`not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace))`</s> to `std::not_fn(isspace)`, which also reads much more like *"is not a space"*.

---

(¹) By the way, stop `using namespace std;`. [It's just the wrong thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

(²) Yes, even if you have to stick to C++14, don't use `std::not1`. In C++14 you already have generic lambdas, so you can define a quasi-`not_fn` yourself ([working example](https://godbolt.org/z/nGcEqWcM6)):

```cpp
auto not_fn = [](auto const& pred){
    return [&pred](auto const& x){
        return !pred(x);
    };
};
```